# GoLang string comparison with Slices

Tags: go

I'm able to get a list of files and folders from a directory, I've written a function called isDir to return True if the path is a directory.

Now my problem is that I want to make sure that none of the folders listed match a list of strings in a slice. The code I have might skip the first match but it will print out everything else anyways. I need to process the folders that aren't to be avoided.

Code is for Windows 7/8 directories but I should be able to get a Linux sample working too should one be provided.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func isDir(pth string) (bool) {
         fi, err := os.Stat(pth)
         if err != nil {
                 return false
         }
         return fi.Mode().IsDir()
}

func main() {
    gcomputer := "localhost"
    location := fmt.Sprintf("\\\\%s\\c$\\Users\\", gcomputer)
    // Profiles to avoid
    avoid := []string{"Administrator", "Default", "Public"}
    // walk through files & folders in the directory (location) & return valid profiles
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(location)
    for _, f := range files {
        fdir := []string{location, f.Name()}
        dpath := strings.Join(fdir, "")

        if isDir(dpath) {
            for _, iavoid := range avoid {
                for iavoid != f.Name() {
                    fmt.Println(dpath)
                    break
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't mind using a third-party module, I've been working on this too long and starting to lose my cool, making understanding the docs a bit difficult. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func avoid(name string) bool {
    profiles := []string{"Administrator", "Default", "Public"}
    for _, p := range profiles {
        if name == p {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    gcomputer := "localhost"
    location := fmt.Sprintf("\\\\%s\\c$\\Users\\", gcomputer)
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(location)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for _, f := range files {
        if f.IsDir() && !avoid(f.Name()) {
            dpath := location + f.Name()
            fmt.Println(dpath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a working example. Not sure why I didn't think of moving the avoid bit into a separate function to simplify things.

Comment: In any case you could also do it without moving the avoid in a separate function...

Answer (score 1):

If your list of strings to avoid gets bigger, you might not want to be iterating over them for every directory. Might I suggest a small modification to @peterSO's answer:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

var avoidanceSet = map[string]bool{
    "Administrator": true,
    "Default": true,
    "Public": true,
}

func avoid(name string) bool {
    _, inSet := avoidanceSet[name]
    return inSet
}

func main() {
    gcomputer := "localhost"
    location := fmt.Sprintf("\\\\%s\\c$\\Users\\", gcomputer)
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(location)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for _, f := range files {
        if f.IsDir() && !avoid(f.Name()) {
            dpath := location + f.Name()
            fmt.Println(dpath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about using a map for this, I appreciate you adding a map example for my current problem. Thank you.